# How do I connect a 1 pin array to a module in pcb using KiCad

Tags: kicad

Because I searched in you tube tutorials, internet and KiCad help guide and I didn’t find anything that can tell how to connect 1 pin array to a module.

this is the type of the 1 pin array. But I'm using just one of this pin array and trying to connecting a resistor (0805) to one end and the other end use it as voltage source.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A 1 pin array of what??  A memory device, a connector, other?  Can you provide a link of a typical device?

Comment: I think we need a better description of your problem.  What exactly is your "one pin array" (to me, an array needs more than one item).  Also, what is the module (size, shape, copnnections)?  In KiCAD, you can make one-pin schematic components and PCB footprints that can be used like any other component and footprint.

Comment: ok thanks and I think i did all the right changes to give a better description of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a one-pin schematic component and associate it with a one-pin PCB footprint (just a single pad).  Place the schematic symbol on the schematic, and connect it as required.  When you load the netlist in PCBNew, the associated footprint will be placed on the PCB, with an airline showing the required connection.

You just treat this "one pin array" as a normal component.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. But I'm having problem with one-pin schematic component, because I'm trying to use conn_1 as one-pin in the schematic, but when I go to CvPcb this conn_1 it doesn't appear in the list to associate a footprint.

Comment: which components you recommend me to use?

Comment: If I wanted such a simple part, I'd make it myself, rather than searching through all the libraries for something almost, but not quite, what I want. If you do any amountof PC design, you _will_ have to make your own parts, so you may as well start now.  When you make a part or modify one from the supplied libraries, save it in your own library, so you won't lose it when you upgrade.  You might find something suitable in a connector library - there's probably a single pin testpoint somewhere.